# how to show sum and mean with two different Y axis in same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I require a ggplot with two Y axis such that primary Y axis with the count (which i will calculate with function `stat=count`) and secondary Y axis showing mean calculated with `stat_summary(fun.y="mean")`

I calculated the count of clusters with:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=cluster,fill=year, stat="count"))+ 
  geom_bar()
```

and mean of divergence with in cluster with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(cluster), y=divergence)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")
```

I have both these ggplots separately. I want to create a ggplot with both these functions such that `count` on `Primary Y axis (geom_bar)` and `Mean` as `secondary Y axis (geom_point and geom_line)`. Anyone one help me with plotting.
Your help will b highly appreciated

```
divergence  year    cluster
0.34    2015    A
0.89    2015    A
1.22    2015    A
1.11    2015    B
0.67    2015    B
0.89    2015    B
1.12    2015    B
0.4     2015    B
0.67    2015    B
0.89    2015    B
0.56    2015    B
1.22    2015    B
1.12    2015    B
0.4     2015    B
0.67    2016    A
0.89    2016    A
0.11    2016    B
1.33    2016    C
1.11    2016    C
1       2016    C
0.89    2016    C
1       2016    C
0.45    2016    C
0.23    2016    C
0.89    2016    C
0.8     2017    A
0.6     2017    A
1.11    2017    A
0.34    2017    B
0.78    2017    B
2.1     2017    C
0.89    2017    C
0.89    2017    C
0.34    2017    C
1.55    2017    A
1.11    2017    A
1.11    2017    A
1       2017    A
0.34    2017    A
0.67    2017    A
0.56    2017    B
1       2017    C
0.34    2017    C
0.23    2017    C
1       2017    C
1.33    2017    C
0.78    2017    C
1.11    2017    B
0.78    2017    C
1       2017    C
0.67    2017    C
0.67    2017    A
0.56    2017    A
1       2017    B
0.34    2017    C
0.67    2017    B
0       2017    B
0.67    2017    B
0.67    2017    B
0.34    2017    B
0.45    2017    B
```

Comment: Why do you want a secondary axis? I think the mean lines/points and the bars can be read from the same axis

Comment: i pasted just a little of my data set...i actuall the sum of my one cluster is 150 where as the mean of divergence is ranged between 0-3

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me why you want a secondary axis when the scales on each axis will be identical but I have included and you can decide if you think it is appropriate.

I'll assume you're familiar with `dplyr`:

First I've created a new dataset with just the mean values for each cluster:

```
df_means <- df %>% group_by(cluster) %>% summarise(mean=mean(divergence))
```

Next I plotted the bar plot along with a line and point for the new dataset. The sec.axis argument in `scale_y_continuous` can be used to create a secondary axis with transformed scale (in this case 1:1)

```
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df,aes(x=cluster,fill=year), stat="count") +
  geom_line(data=df_means,aes(x=cluster,y=mean, group=1,color='Average')) +
  geom_point(data=df_means,aes(x=cluster,y=mean,color='Average'))+
  scale_y_continuous("Count", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans =  ~. ,name = 
  'Average'))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

UPDATE:

Thanks for uploading the additional data, I understand why you wanted the secondary axis now. And you can apply a transformation to the secondary axis using the `trans` parameter - in this case I just specified that the secondary axis is one-tenth the scale of the primary one.

You will then need to do the reverse transformation to the line and point you want displayed on the secondary axis - in this case multiplied by 10.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df,aes(x=cluster,fill=year), stat="count") +
  geom_line(data=df_means,aes(x=cluster,y=mean*10, group=1,color='Average')) +
  geom_point(data=df_means,aes(x=cluster,y=mean*10,color='Average'))+
  scale_y_continuous("Count", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans =  ~ ./10 ,name = 
                                                'Average'))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: just one more thing how i can reduce the sec y axis in this case average as in my case it is mean of divergence and its range is from 0-3

Comment: your help will b highly appreciated

Comment: i managed to change the scale of y axis but my geom line on sec y axis is not synchronizing with the scale. my geom_line outcome is lying flat at the bottom. can any one help me in this regard

Comment: @nayab Have updated my answer to include a transformation of the axis

Comment: @nayab feel free to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: thank you for your help i managed to draw required graph based on help provided. best regrads